# Getting errors when I try to install lubuntu from the terminal

Tags: lubuntu

I've been trying to install the lubuntu desktop, but it gives me this error. Is there anything I can do, or should I not even try? I'm new at this, please make it simple.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lubuntu-desktop : Depends: lubuntu-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```